# Conditional Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to find $P(X_1=k\mid X_1+X_2=n)$, given $X_1$ and $X_2$ have Poisson distribution. I'm really stuck with it. Can anyone help how to proceed?

Comment: consider $P(X_2 = n-k)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
P(X_1=k\mid X_1+X_2=n) &= \frac{P((X_1=k) \cap (X_1+X_2=n))}{P(X_1+X_2=n)}\\
&= \frac{P((X_1=k)\cap(X_2=n-k))}{P(X_1+X_2=n)}\\
&=\frac{P(X_1=k))P(X_2=n-k)}{P(X_1+X_2=n)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: It's $\frac{\mathsf P(X_1{=}k)\,\mathsf P(X_2{=}n-k)}{\mathsf P(X_1+X_2{=}n)}$, since the value of $X_1$ isn't at all fixed by the knowing value of $X_2$; and indeed they are independent.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If the distributions have intensities $\lambda$ and $\mu$, respectively, each item independently has probability $\lambda/(\lambda+\mu)$ and $\mu/(\lambda+\mu)$, respectively, to come from $X_1$ or $X_2$. Thus the probability for $k$ items to come from $X_1$ is

$$
\binom nk\frac{\lambda^k\mu^{n-k}}{(\lambda+\mu)^n}\;.
$$